# Substring SQL Select statement

Tags: substring

I have a number of references with a length of 20 and I need to remove the 1st 12 numbers, replace with a G and select the next 7 numbers

An example of the format of the numbers being received

```
50125426598525412584
```

I then need to remove first 12 digits and select the next 7 (not including the last)

```
2541258
```

Lastly I need to put a G in front of the number so I'm left with

```
G25412584
```

My SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ref, 12, 7) AS ref 
FROM mytable
WHERE ref LIKE '5012%'
```

The results of this will leave me with

```
25412584
```

But how do I insert the `G` in front of the number in the same SQL statement?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 'G'+SUBSTRING(ref, 12, 7) AS ref FROM mytable where ref like '5012%'
```

Comment: Gabriel, really appreciate your response. I am trying to do an insert based on the results of the select but getting a

Comment: what do you have exactly? and does the row actually exist?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'G', SUBSTRING('50125426598525412584', 13,7)) from dual;
```